# Logarithm of absolute value of a harmonic function subharmonic?

Tags: harmonic-functions

If $f(x)$ is harmonic, then is $\log|f(x)|$ a subharmonic function?  I know if $f(x)$ is analytic, this is true, but for harmonic $f(x)$, is it still true? Thanks!